# Java - How to stop text from flickering when using setText() quickly

Tags: java, swing

So I have been having some trouble trying to create a teletype effect for my swing program. I essentially want to update a JFrame at 40ms increments with a new letter, "typing" out a message to the user. However, it flickers a lot when I try to do this. The method is below:

```
public static void animateTeletype(String input, JTextArea displayArea) 
       throws InterruptedException {
    displayArea.setText("");
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        s += input.substring(i, i+1);
        displayArea.setText(textToDisplay);
        Thread.sleep(40);
        displayArea.update(displayArea.getGraphics());
    }
}
```

I figure the problem stems from updating the text too fast, and it has to update more than it can handle. I am not sure how I would go about this issue, as reducing tick time will make text scroll too slowly. Any advice is appreciated!

** I've solved the problem. This is my new code:

```
static Timer timer = null;
public static void animateTeletype(final String input, final JTextArea displayArea) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final String[] s = new String[1];
        s[0] = " ";
        final int[] i = new int[1];
        i[0] = 0;
        displayArea.setText("");    
        timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                s[0] = input.substring(i[0], i[0]+1);
                i[0]++;
                displayArea.append(s[0]);
                if(displayArea.getText().equals(input))
                    timer.stop();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: I hope you're not running that code on your [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
displayArea.update(displayArea.getGraphics());
```

Don't use the update() method. There is never any reason to do that. Get rid of that statement.

Swing components will automatically repaint themselves.

```
displayArea.setText(textToDisplay);
```

Don't uset setText(...) to add new text.

Instead you should be using:

```
displayArea.append( "some more text" );
```

Don't use Thread.sleep(40) for animation. It you want animation then use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation.

I suggest you look at other section of the tutorial for Swing basics. Maybe something like `How to Use Text Fields`.

Comment: When I don't include the update line, the component doesn't seem to update until the for statement completes. It waits a bit, and then the entire string gets displayed.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond, Tell us what your solution was, it will be useful to others.

Comment: `the component doesn't seem to update until the for statement completes.` - that is because of the Thread.sleep(). I told you the proper solution. 1) get rid of the Thread.sleep(), 2) get rid of the update(...) method. 3. Use a Swing Timer.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the Thread.sleep(). Instead, I have used timer, but it still doesn't seem to scroll the text.

Comment: @ThomasRichmond, the text should scroll automatically. See [Text Area Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for more information. If you need more help then ask a new question with a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem .